# ReactJS lifecycle methods not working in sequence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-google-maps

I am working on Google Maps rendering in ReactJS. For that, I am using 'react-google-maps' library. The logical flow is; at the page load, get the user's location and plot them on the map. 
A user is provided with navigation links to hit different URL. To handle the navigation, I am using React router. The user's location is identified in componentWillMount() then the state is set accordingly and the map is rendered in render(). 
The problem is that render() gets called before completing componentWillMount(), it gets the null values and it fails. This situation only occurs in client-side routing and not in server-side rendering.

To restrict the way of execution, I made the componentWillMount() as an async method where it waits until the user's location is determined. Still, it was not helpful.

```
state = {
        homeLocation: {},
        coordinates: []
    }

async componentWillMount(props) {
        const { lat,lng } = await this.getcurrentLocation();
        this.setState({
            homeLocation:{
                lat: lat, 
                lng: lng
            }
        })
    }

getcurrentLocation() {

        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
              const coords = pos.coords;
              resolve({
                lat: coords.latitude,
                lng: coords.longitude
              });
            });
          });
        }
        return {
          lat: 0,
          lng: 0
        };
      }
render(){

   <MapWithAMarker
   // necessary parameters
  />
}

//Routers
const AppRouter = () => (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={MapHomeLocation} exact={true}/>
                <Route path="/location/:locationType" component={MapSelectedLocation}/>
                <Route component={Notfound}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>

    </Router>
);


The expected result is that coordinates should be determined first then render() should get called. In server-side routing(i.e. using anchor tags instead of <Link>) it works as expected.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check like that if data is there in that then only give value.

if data && data.length > 0 ? data : null

Comment: Can you please explain to me where I can put this condition? I am new to ReactJS concepts. Your comment will be helpful.

Comment: because when you doing and fetch some data for api then first time its get null so that we need to check and put condition inside if data is null then don't assign if data is not null then assign @Swapnil

Comment: remove async  and await in componentwilmount method

Comment: put getcurrentLocation() inside the component will mount

Comment: if you want more help then we can connet in anydesk i wil help you.

Comment: I tried a similar solution earlier in render() method. But I got an error saying, maximum update depth exceeded. My solution was, if the data is null then use setState. But it did not work. Can you share the code snippet, I will figure it out.

Comment: Can you provide me anydesk address. I can connect you

Comment: anydesk 529 414 519

Comment: give me your id i am available to help you @Swapnil

Comment: Thanks Mehul for me helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

Call the getcurrentLocation() in the state itself.

```js
state = {
        homeLocation: this.getcurrentLocation(),
        coordinates: []
    }



getcurrentLocation() {

        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
              const coords = pos.coords;
              resolve({
                lat: coords.latitude,
                lng: coords.longitude
              });
            });
          });
        }
        return {
          lat: 0,
          lng: 0
        };
      }
render(){

   <MapWithAMarker
   // necessary parameters
  />
}

//Routers
const AppRouter = () => (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={MapHomeLocation} exact={true}/>
                <Route path="/location/:locationType" component={MapSelectedLocation}/>
                <Route component={Notfound}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>

    </Router>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you don't mind asking the code snippet to set the values in state. Since getcurrentLocation() returns two values, how can I assign them to homeLocation object in state.

Answer (score 1):

Never do fetching operations in `componentWillMount()`, instead use `componentDidMount()` since calling `setState()` would re-render the component, you probably will see new data appears on your map.

Comment: what behavior ?

Comment: Getting null coordinates in the render method. With componentWillMount(), it gets coordinates sometimes.